# How to enable remote login via terminal for single user

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

Does anybody know what is the command to allow "Only these users" into remote login for mac ?

I have enable the remote login via terminal using " sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on "

I will need to add a username into allow access only for that particular user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The list of users is controlled by the `com.apple.access_ssh` group.

- If the group doesn't exist, Remote Login is set to ‘All users’.
- If the group exists and has members, Remote Login is set to ‘Only these users’.
- If Remote Login is disabled, the group is renamed `com.apple.access_ssh-disabled` which preserves members for when it is enabled.

You can see the group and manually edit it using Workgroup Manager without Terminal for testing.

[image: Workgroup Manager showing SSH Service ACL group]

To reset all settings and enable Remote Login, you can run the following. In my testing, it has not been necessary to disable remote login using the first command, but I include it for completeness.

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin off
dseditgroup -o delete -q com.apple.access_ssh
dseditgroup -o delete -q com.apple.access_ssh-disabled
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

To add a user to the group using the command line, you can use `dseditgroup`, replacing ‘username’ with the username of the user to grant access to.

```
dseditgroup -o create -q username -t user com.apple.access_ssh
```